# AvalonEdit :: How do I preserve current state in the UndoStack?

Tags: avalonedit

I am currently working on implementing AvalonEdit in an HTML WYSIWYG/"Source Code" side-by-side editor.  When the user switches from Design Mode (a `RichTextBox`) to Source Mode (AvalonEdit `TextEditor`) the XAML from the RTB is converted to HTML and written to the `TextEditor.Document.Text` property.

This apparently wipes out the undo stack.

How can I push the state of the Document to the `UndoStack` so the user can "go back"?  I tried wrapping the write operation in a `RunUpdate() IDisposable`, but that didn't work:

```
using (var _ = TextEditor.Document.RunUpdate())
{
   TextEditor.Document.Text = html;
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a couple years late, I'm not sure if it answers the question directly.  However, the current release of AvalonEdit functions such that setting `TextEditor.Text` will clear the undo stack, but modifying `TextEditor.Document.Text` will not.  (This runs counter to the behavior observed by the asker, so perhaps it has changed in the couple years since).  Looking at the source code, `TextEditor.Document.Text` appears to execute code equivalent to

```
this.Replace(0, this.TextLength, value);
```

so perhaps a similar call would work even on older versions of the library.